# cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm using a script to create tables and insert data into the tables but my script has a few errors.
I've been searching online but, no luck, here are the errors:

```
ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect integer value: '' for column `a4_mgarr048_count`.`airline`.`total` at row 1
cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'

ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect integer value: '' for column `a4_mgarr048_count`.`airline`.`total` at row 1
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields

at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(name varchar(255), tot                                                                                                                                                        al int)' at line 1
```

and here is my script:

```
readarray -d , -t header <<< "gender,state,municipality,season,continent,elective,f1,airline"
for (( n=0; n < ${#header[@]} +1 ; n++))
do
  mysql -D a4_mgarr048_count -e "create table ${header[n]} (name varchar(255),total int);"
done

readarray -d , -t header <<< "gender:4,state:6,municipality:7,season:8,continent:9,elective:10,f1:11,airline:12"
for  (( n=0; n < ${#header[@]} +1; n++))
do
  readarray -d : -t fields <<< ${header[n]}
  while read line 
  do
    mysql -D a4_mgarr048_count -e "insert into ${fields[0]} values ('$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2)','$(echo $line | cut -d, f1)')"
    done < <(cat /root/mgarr048.csv | cut -d, -f${fields[1]} | sort | uniq -c |sed -e 's/^\s*//g' -e 's/ /,/g')
    done
```

Comment: `cut -d, -f${fields[1]}` So, what happens when `fields[1]` is unset or empty?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting an array and then looping over it you can just loop over the values; this also avoids `readarray -d, <<<string` including a newline in the last entry which then splits wrong. Plus awk can in one step do the field selection, counting, and reformatting, and mysql can insert multiple rows in one operation. Thus:

```
db=a4_mgarr048_count; input=/root/mgarr048.csv 

for a in gender state municipality season continent elective f1 airline; do
  mysql -D$db -e"create table $a (name varchar(255),total int);"
done

for f in gender:4 state:6 municipality:7 season:8 continent:9 elective:10 f1:11 airline:12; do
  IFS=: read a b <<<$f
  mysql -D$db -e"insert into $a values $( awk <$input -F, -vfld=$b -vORS= \
    '{cnt[$fld]++} END{for(i in cnt){print s"(\47"i"\47,"cnt[i]")";s=","}}' );"
  #non-GNU awk may require -v fld=$b -v ORS= everything else is standard
done
```

or combine the loops as

```
for f in gender:4 state:6 municipality:7 season:8 continent:9 elective:10 f1:11 airline:12; do
  IFS=: read a b <<<$f
  mysql -D$db -e"create table $a (name varchar(255),total int);"
  mysql -D$db -e"insert into $a values $( awk <$input -F, -vfld=$b -vORS= \
    '{cnt[$fld]++} END{for(i in cnt){print s"(\47"i"\47,"cnt[i]")";s=","}}'
done
```